# dynamic artistic pixalation of any photo using .net window forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image-processing, pixel

i have written this code to draw an artistic pixilation of inputed image. but i am unable to get the result which i want. can someone help me by reviewing my code. i am using window forms .net.

Desired ouput has been shown in this picture

[image: 1]

my code is this :

```
private void DrawShape(Graphics g, Brush brush, int x, int y, int size)
{
    int halfSize = size / 2;
    int xOffset = chkOverlap.Checked ? -halfSize : 0;
    int yOffset = chkOverlap.Checked ? -halfSize : 0;

    if (chkCircle.Checked)
    {
        // Draw the outer circle
        g.FillEllipse(brush, x + xOffset, y + yOffset, size, size);

        // Draw the first inner circle (blue color)
        using (Brush innerBrush1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue))
        {
            int innerSize1 = size / 2;
            int innerX1 = x + halfSize - innerSize1 / 2 + xOffset;
            int innerY1 = y + halfSize - innerSize1 / 2 + yOffset;
            g.FillEllipse(innerBrush1, innerX1, innerY1, innerSize1, innerSize1);
        }

        // Draw the second inner circle (red color)
        using (Brush innerBrush2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
        {
            int innerSize2 = size / 3;
            int innerX2 = x + halfSize - innerSize2 / 2 + xOffset;
            int innerY2 = y + halfSize - innerSize2 / 2 + yOffset;
            g.FillEllipse(innerBrush2, innerX2, innerY2, innerSize2, innerSize2);
        }
    }
    else if (chkSquare.Checked)
    {
        g.FillRectangle(brush, x + xOffset, y + yOffset, size, size);
    }
    else if (chkTriangle.Checked)
    {
        PointF[] trianglePoints = new PointF[]
        {
            new PointF(x + size / 2 + xOffset, y + yOffset),
            new PointF(x + xOffset, y + size + yOffset),
            new PointF(x + size + xOffset, y + size + yOffset)
        };
        g.FillPolygon(brush, trianglePoints);
    }
    else if (chkRectangle.Checked)
    {
        g.FillRectangle(brush, x + xOffset, y + yOffset, size * 2, size);
    }
}
```

code is generating this image. but i want the result like i have shown in above photo.

[image: 2]

tried this

```
private void DrawShape(Graphics g, Brush brush, int x, int y, int size)
{
    int halfSize = size / 2;
    int xOffset = chkOverlap.Checked ? -halfSize : 0;
    int yOffset = chkOverlap.Checked ? -halfSize : 0;

    if (chkCircle.Checked)
    {
        // Draw the outer circle
        g.FillEllipse(brush, x + xOffset, y + yOffset, size, size);

        // Draw the first inner circle (blue color)
        using (Brush innerBrush1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue))
        {
            int innerSize1 = size / 2;
            int innerX1 = x + halfSize - innerSize1 / 2 + xOffset;
            int innerY1 = y + halfSize - innerSize1 / 2 + yOffset;
            g.FillEllipse(innerBrush1, innerX1, innerY1, innerSize1, innerSize1);
        }

        // Draw the second inner circle (red color)
        using (Brush innerBrush2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
        {
            int innerSize2 = size / 3;
            int innerX2 = x + halfSize - innerSize2 / 2 + xOffset;
            int innerY2 = y + halfSize - innerSize2 / 2 + yOffset;
            g.FillEllipse(innerBrush2, innerX2, innerY2, innerSize2, innerSize2);
        }
    }
    else if (chkSquare.Checked)
    {
        g.FillRectangle(brush, x + xOffset, y + yOffset, size, size);
    }
    else if (chkTriangle.Checked)
    {
        PointF[] trianglePoints = new PointF[]
        {
            new PointF(x + size / 2 + xOffset, y + yOffset),
            new PointF(x + xOffset, y + size + yOffset),
            new PointF(x + size + xOffset, y + size + yOffset)
        };
        g.FillPolygon(brush, trianglePoints);
    }
    else if (chkRectangle.Checked)
    {
        g.FillRectangle(brush, x + xOffset, y + yOffset, size * 2, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so you want it regular or irregular? either just needs you to have some idea of how to do it. for the irregular result, you'll need to randomize the size of circles. this might need some iteration (gradient descent) on the position and size of circles, to look good.

Comment: ok but what about colors , i mean  if you have seen my required result image it has different colors in patches how to do this ?

Comment: that's no longer a programming problem, that's a matter of style.